# Erro: "can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'"

Tags: python, python-3.x, float

Estou fazendo esse simples conversor de de unidades.

Preciso que ele faça:

- Cálculo da velocidade média em `Km/h`;
- Imprima este resultado.

Depois, em uma outra função, preciso converter-lo para `m/s` e imprimir novamente o resultado.

Mas fico recebendo o seguinte erro no Output do trecho de código que anexei abaixo:

> "can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'"

```
dist_k1= 169.0
time_h1= 0.6

dist_k2= 169.0
time_h2= 1.0

dist_k3= 300.0
time_h3= 1.5

def get_deltaV(dist_k, time_h):
    DeltaV = dist_k/time_h
    return DeltaV,"Km/h"

DeltaV1= get_deltaV(dist_k1, time_h1)
DeltaV2= get_deltaV(dist_k2,time_h2)
DeltaV3= get_deltaV(dist_k3,time_h3)

print(DeltaV1)
print(DeltaV2)
print(DeltaV3)

def get_ms (DeltaV):
    ms =DeltaV / 3.6
    return (ms,"m/s")

ms1 = get_ms(DeltaV1)
ms2 = get_ms(DeltaV2)
ms3 = get_ms(DeltaV3)

print(ms1)
print(ms2)
print(ms3)
```

Por que este erro está ocorrendo? Como posso corrigi-lo?

Comment: `get_deltaV` retorna uma tupla e esse retorno você está passando como parâmetro para `get_ms`, onde o valor é multiplicado por 3.6. Não deveria ser `get_ms(DeltaV1[0])`?

Comment: Funcionou, obrigado

Comment: Mas qual seria a razão disso?

Comment: Do que? Do erro? Qual seria o resultado esperado para a operação `(10, 'km/h') / 3.6`?

Comment: seria então porque está dividindo uma tupla?

Comment: Exatamente, como comentei inicialmente quando ainda estava a multiplicação.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Os comentários já responderam, mas segue o código um pouco mais pythonico:

```
from collections import namedtuple

routes = namedtuple('Routes', ['dist_k', 'time_h'])

routes = map(routes._make, [
    (169.0, 0.6),
    (169.0, 1.0),
    (300.0, 1.5)
])


def get_delta_v(*route):
    delta_v = route[0] / route[1]
    return delta_v, '{} Km/h'.format(delta_v)


def get_ms(delta_v):
    ms = delta_v / 3.6
    return ms, '{} m/s'.format(delta_v)


for route in routes:
    print(get_delta_v(*route)[1])
    print(get_ms(get_delta_v(*route)[0])[1])
```

Comment: Se importa de me explicar as mudanças? Estou aprendendo Python ainda então qualquer explicação já é estudo.

Comment: Claro @MarcelloFabrizio, você pode usar o `namedtuple` sempre que for trabalhar com constantes, no seu caso você tem uma sequência fixa que seriam distância e tempo, por isso usei `namedtuple`, ela traz alguns benefícios ex: acesso via (dot notation) ou acesso como se fosse uma `tupla`,`route.dist_k` ou `route[0]`.
Outra correçāo foi na declaraçāo de variaveis, em python se usa camelCase apenas em classes, em variáveis ou métodos e usa o snake case `_`